# Is this the right way to use dependency injection with the Service Container?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

So, I have Two different classes:

**Class A**

```
class A implements SomeContract
{
    public function extraThicc()
    {
        return 'Filthy Frank';
    } 
}
```

**Class B**

```
class B implements SomeContract
{
    public function extraThicc()
    {
        return 'iDubbbz';
    } 
}
```

**Interface**

```
interface SomeContract
{
    public function extraThicc();
}
```

**Boss Class**

```
class Boss
{
    public $someVar

    public function __construct(SomeContract $someVar)
    {
        $this->someVar = $someVar;
    }
}
```

**The Service Provider**

```
    $this->app->bind('Boss::class', function($app,$param){
        if ($param['type'] == 'A') return new A();
        if ($param['type'] == 'B') return new B();
    });
```

**The Resolving**

```
public function boss($type)
{
    return app()->makeWith('Boss::class', ['type'=>$type')]);
}
```

**The Facade**

```
class CoolFacade extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'cool'; }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
class StarWarsBattlefrontController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return 'Star Wars: Battlefront 2 Loot Boxes are bad, says:'.Cool::Boss('A')->extraThicc();
    }
}
```

Is there a better method to inject dependencys into the class? Because I don't think this's a good practice to use if statments in the bind method of the Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your approach isn't really Dependency Injection, but Facades. If you read [Laravel Docs on Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/facades#when-to-use-facades) you can see they just describe them as easy accessor, but they should not be abused. Instead, dependencies must be injected.

For what you need, you might wanna read on [Contextual Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container#binding), which would be something like

```
$this->app->when(BossA::class)
          ->needs(SomeContract::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new A;
          });

$this->app->when(BossB::class)
          ->needs(SomeContract::class)
          ->give(function () {
              return new B;
          });
```

Comment: My problem here is, that I use 3 different classes: GoogleMaps, OSRM, MapBox.They share the same function names (The methods are smiliar).Is there a method, that can return a class when it's needed ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish. Perhaps updating your question would help(?).

Comment: `$this->app->bind('\App\Acme\GeoServices\Geo::class', function($app,$param){
            if ($param['type'] == 'Google') return new GoogleMaps($param);
            if ($param['type'] == 'Mapbox') return new Mapbox($param);
            if ($param['type'] == 'OSRM') return new OpenStreetMaps($param);
        });`


Something like this, so when I need the the OSRM class, I'll just return

`Flow::GIS('OSRM')->routes('ARAD.AL-ARYAN.KEFAR GALLIM.KEFAR SHEMARYAHU.NEWE UR.REKHASIM')->distance();`

Comment: Again, the pattern you're using for calling the implementation object is not dependency injection. That's a Facade. I linked you to the docs so you can read about it.   And for multiple implementation of an instance, read on contextual binding, which I also already linked.